# why does field value comes as 1'000,24 instead of 1,000.24 when the format is >,>>>,>>9.99 in progress 4gl?

Tags: openedge

> we have recently upgraded to oe rdbms 11.3 version from 9.1d. While generating
>   reports,i found the field value of a field comes as 2'239,00 instead of 
>   2,239.00.I checked the format its >,>>>,>>9.99.
>   what could be the reason behind this?

Comment: This is typically Swiss notation. Check if your locale isn't set on any Swiss locale by default.

Comment: You have had two quite good answers. You should at least upvote and select one of them... That's good karma you know!

Comment: Sorry,i will strictly follow this hereafter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The admin installing the database didn't to it's homework and selected wrong default numeric and decimal separator.

However no greater harm done:

Set these startup parameters

```
-numsep 44 -numdec 46
```

This is an simplified database startup example with added parameters as above:

```
proserve /db/db -H dbserver -S dbservice -numsep 44 -numdec 46
```

Comment: Simply add "-numsep 44 -numdec 46" without quotes to startup scripts (both database and client startups).

Comment: Could i change these valuese in installd.ini file to numsep = 44 and -numdec = 46 and save the file?

Comment: No, if you don't want to add the parameters you need to reinstall software.

Comment: Usually aqn -e is the startup parameter we use. wnen i use aqn -e -numsep 44 -numdec 46 it says too many parameters given.

Comment: I have no idea what "aqn" is. Check if aqn is a script in itself containing startup commands - then perhaps you can edit it? If you use some kind of product utilizing Progress perhaps you should contact your vendor?

Comment: -e has been obsolete and unused for 20 years.

Answer (score 0):

When you install Progress you are prompted for the numeric format to use.  That information is then written to a file called "startup.pf" which is located in the install directory (C:\Progress\OpenEdge by default on  Windows...)

If you picked the wrong numeric format you can edit startup.pf with any text editor.  It should look something like this:

```
#This is a placeholder startup.pf
#You may put any global startup parameters you desire
#in this file.  They will be used by ALL Progress modules
#including the client, server, utilities, etc.
#
#The file dlc/prolang/locale.pf provides examples of
#settings for the different options that vary internationally.
#
#The directories under dlc/prolang contain examples of
#startup.pf settings appropriate to each region.
#For example, the file dlc/prolang/ger/german.pf shows
#settings that might be used in Germany.
#The file dlc/prolang/ger/geraus.pf gives example settings
#for German-speaking Austrians.
#
#Copy the file that seems appropriate for your region or language
#over this startup.pf. Edit the file to meet your needs.
#
# e.g. UNIX:            cp /dlc/prolang/ger/geraus.pf /dlc/startup.pf
# e.g. DOS, WINDOWS:  copy \dlc\prolang\ger\geraus.pf \dlc\startup.pf
#
# You may want to include these same settings in /dlc/ade.pf.
#
#If the directory for your region or language does not exist in
#dlc/prolang, please check that you have ordered AND installed the
#International component. The International component provides
#these directories and files.
#

-cpinternal ISO8859-1
-cpstream ISO8859-1
-cpcoll Basic
-cpcase Basic
-d mdy
-numsep 44
-numdec 46
```

Changes to the startup.pf file are **GLOBAL** -- they impact all sessions started on this machine.  If you only want to change a single session then you can add the parameters to the command line (or the shortcut icons properties) or to a local .pf file or to an ini file being used by that session.

You can also programmatically override the format in your code by using the SESSION system handle:

```
assign
  session:numeric-decimal-point = "."
  session:numeric-separator     = ","
.

display 123456.999.
```

(You might want to consider saving the current values  and restoring them if this is a temporary change.)

(You can also use the shorthand session:numeric-format = "american". or "european" for the two most  common cases.)

Comment: Thanks tom, i edited startup.pf and saved.Everything looks fine now.